# ngx-image-zoom set max-width and -height

Tags: angular

`ngx-image-zoom` is a great product. After some testing we found out it will be necessary to set a `max-width` so a large image won't bump other content off the cliff.

No matter what we do like the followings and/or combination won't do the tricks to contain and auto-resize it

- `<lib-ngx-image-zoom style="max-width:100px" ...>`
- `<div style="width:100px; max-width:100px">`

F12 shows it has this setting

```
<div _ngcontent-tnl-c230="" class="ngxImageZoomContainer" style="width: 773px; height: 768px;">
```

manually decreased the width and height just like cut out and show the corresponding area from upper left corner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add this to the CSS and it will work

```
::ng-deep .ngxImageZoomContainer > img{
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    :host {
  ::ng-deep .ngxImageZoomContainer {
    width: 100% !important;
  }

  ::ng-deep .ngxImageZoomThumbnail {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?